# How to create a custom analyzer for full-text index in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, full-text-search

I want to create a custom analyzer for Neo4j Full-text Index.

I tried to clone repositories from:

https://github.com/covidgraph/neo4j-additional-analyzers (repo 1) and

https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-lucene-custom-analyzer (repo 2)

And then do `mvn clean package`.

Then copy the .jar file to the plugins folder.

I use Neo4j Desktop (Windows 10), the plugins folder location:
`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Neo4j\Relate\Data\dbmss\dbms-6682c57d-3895-4b8e-a465-d9d2891e8dca\plugins`

I also try to use Neo4j Docker, the plugin folder location:
`/var/lib/neo4j/plugins`

I restart Neo4j and try to run cypher command like this to get the list of available analyzer:

`CALL db.index.fulltext.listAvailableAnalyzers`

But there is no custom analyzer.

I also try to create index like this:

`CALL db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex("movieTitle",["Movie"],["title"], { analyzer: "whitespace_lower" })`

But I get the following error:

`Failed to invoke procedure db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such full-text analyzer: 'whitespace_lower'.`

Note: "whitespace_lower" is the name of the custom analyzer from repo 1, when I try using repo 2, I get the same error. The name of the custom analyzer from repo 2 is "custom_stopwords".

Comment: What Neo4j version are you using ? As you can see on the graphaware one, it was demoed on Neo4j 3.5.5

Comment: Ohh I'm using Neo4j 4.1.1, I thought it doesn't really matter because repo 1 said Neo4j >= 3.4